# .htaccess Allow access not file by link only

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I know that is possible to limit the access to a directory by the `allow from ip.ip.ip.ip` directive.

But I've got a slightly(?) different problem:
There is a directory, that contains pdf files only. I want to restrict the access to these files:
- When you try to display these pdf files by typing the link in your browser, e. g. `http://domain/pdf_path/pdf1.pdf` the call should fail.
- But if the user opens the file by clicking on a link from in `http://domain/`, e. g. from the source file `http://domain/index.php`, the pdf file should be displayed.

Is there a way to achieve this in the .htaccess (not http.conf) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header in `.htaccess`. The referer indicates the address of the web page that linked to the resource being fetched - so you could check that the referer points to a page on the right domain.

For details, see e.g. this question: [control apache referrer to restrict downloads in htaccess file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88874/control-apache-referrer-to-restrict-downloads-in-htaccess-file)

**Warning:**

This is easy to circumvent if people know the name of the domain that you are checking for. Most browsers and download tools allow setting the referer directly, so if you know that only referers pointing to `http://foo.example/` are allowed, you can just set your referer to `http://foo.example/blah`, and the access check will not block you.

If you want serious security, the only sensible option it probably proper authentication (by username/password or by certificat), combined with an HTTPS-only website.